# "Half Hour" Intervals for date Method

Tags: php, date

This seems like a basic question and I don't see if it has been asked before:

I have this `if` statement in a script:

`if (date('H') < $loc_item -> closing) {`

Basically it's a script for business.  And it has to do with when a store closes.  6 o'clock, 7 o'clock, etc.

The variable uses values 1 - 24 for hour only.  However, SOME business close at, 5:30 PM (17:30), 6:30 PM (18:30),

Would a value of 18.5 represent 6:30 PM?  **If not**, what is the simplest way to enter use the date function where I can add a value of `1830` and it knows I mean 6:30PM?

**Edit**:  There is NO user output here.  The script just needs to know to throw a "switch" at a certain time of day.

Comment: Date H will only return a whole number so 17.5 would represent everything up to 17:59.

Comment: Why not store `$loc_item->closing` as `17:30` and then simply check if `date('H:i') < $loc_item->closing`? Also, see my answer for a more proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `date` function to return hours and minutes, then `date('H')` isn't going to do it for you. You need `date('Hi')`. That returns a string. The following is a complete code snippet:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo "The time is ".date('Hi')."\n";
$closingTime = "12:15";
echo "The store closes at ".$closingTime."\n";
if (strtotime(date('Hi')) < strtotime($closingTime)) echo "it is still open\n";
else echo "the store is closed\n";
?>
```

Sample output:

```
The time is 1225
The store closes at 12:15
the store is closed
```

Comment: Basically, an admin will put in a 4-digit number in a form to a Database.  For example, `1830`.   As long as `php` reads this as 6:30PM when it sees that value -- that is all I need.  So if `closing` attribute is `1830` and I did `if (date('Hi') < $loc_item -> closing) {`  would this be all I need in the comparison?

Comment: You don't need the `:` in the time string. Not sure you can get away with not converting the time with `strtotime` though - since the value returned is otherwise a string, and I'm not sure if the string comparison will guarantee that if time1 < time2, then string1<string2 .

Comment: So this then:  `if (date('Hi') < date("Hi", strtotime($loc_item -> closing)) {`   Does that make more sense?

Comment: Marking you right as this ultimately helped me implement it... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
date("Hi", strtotime("18:40"));
```

Comment: I do not understand the `date("Hi"),`?

Comment: "Hi" is a format string. `H` means Hour and `i` means Minute.

Comment: Whoops, indeed was too quick on this one. In your case, you can also replace Hi with g:i A to get it in AM/PM format

Comment: @JoeFrambach  Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that.  I was reading it as "Hello!" - Of course its a date string!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't really giving us enough information to answer the question.

First off, you might as well make your script support all minutes...cause some stores might close @ 6:45.

I think the solution you are looking for is to simply do a comparision of timestamps.

The easiest way to do this is using [strtotime.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to do something like:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$closing = new DateTime('19:30');

if ($now < $closing) // not closed
```

I assume you don't have to worry about stores closing in the early AM.

Comment: This does seem like a simple version... and correct assumption!